# trying to create aurelia routing in plunker

Tags: aurelia

I am working on creating a page in `plunker` to demo `aurelia routing`. Here is the [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/5R8dg2?p=preview). For some reason, I am unable to show the route in the page. I am able to run similar code in my local environment just fine. I think it is something in plunker that has to be done differently.

Here is the code:

**app.html**

```
<template>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <div class="row col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
    <div class="btn-group col-sm-offset-1" role="group" aria-label="...">
      <a repeat.for="row of router.navigation" class="${row.isActive ? 'active btn btn-primary' : 'btn btn-default'}" href.bind="row.href">
        ${row.title}
      </a>
    </div>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

**app.ts**

```
import { Aurelia, PLATFORM } from "aurelia-framework";
import { Router, RouterConfiguration } from "aurelia-router";

export class App {
  router: Router;
  // Configure Routing
  configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router): void {
    console.log("Aurelia routing");
    config.title = "Aurelia Routing";
    // config.options.root = "/";
    config.map([
      {
        route: "",
        redirect: "home",
        settings: { icon: "home" }
      },
      {
        route: "home",
        moduleId: "./Home",
        nav: true,
        title: "Home",
        settings: { icon: "home" }
      },
      {
        route: "/support",
        moduleId: "./Support",
        nav: true,
        title: "Support Request",
        settings: { icon: "home" }
      }
    ]);
    this.router = router;
    console.log(router);
  }
  // console.log(this.router);
}
```

Further details, such as bootstrapping, etc can be found in [plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/5R8dg2?p=preview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a typo/error in your `main.ts`:

```
aurelia.use.basicConfiguration()
```

Should be:

```
aurelia.use.standardConfiguration()
```

Changing this, I saw the `console.log` messages you put in the configuration, but I got another error, but the routing works now.

Comment: Thanks Jesse. I will look in to the other issue, but I do see that it now executes routing configuration from `app.ts`  file.